# Spring Configurations as a Bean (alternative to Import)

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have many configurations that I want to group into a single one and I'd like to avoid the use of Import because I want to be able to overwrite a given configuration.
Say.

```
// ------- In the library

@Configuration
public class LibConfig{

@Bean
 public BaseConfig getBaseConfig(){
  return new BaseConfig()
 }
 //[...Other configs...]
}

// -------- In the main project

@Configuration
public class DerivedConfig extends BaseConfig(){ 
// Overload some bean definition
}

@Configuration
public class AppConfig extends LibConfig {
@Bean
 public BaseConfig getBaseConfig(){
  return new DerivedConfig();
 }
}
```

But it seems that the configurations are not loaded.
Which is the correct approach?

Answer (score -1):

As per Spring documentation - section [`6. Using the @SpringBootApplication Annotation`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using.html#using.using-the-springbootapplication-annotation)

> @ComponentScan: enable @Component scan on the package where the application is located (see the best practices)

So my guess would be that `@Configuration` annotated classes you want included are residing in a different package than application class. Either put them in some common package or adjust `@ComponentScan` option of application.

Comment: I'm NOT using component scan

Comment: Man, anyway your answers doesn't even touch our resolve the problem. Component scanning prevents bean overloading.